# IBM Cloud Private ... LDAP ... no go

Tags: ldap, ibm-cloud-private

I am working for an IBM Business Partner and I am trying to complete a first PoC ICP installation. The basic installation has worked. I did not configure LDAP during the deployment but I am trying to add an LDAP connection in the console now, afterwards.

Unfortunately, I always fail. And there seem to be a number for limitations and/or bugs in the LDAP connection of ICP to the point of making it unuseable.

First, I would like to connect to an IBM Domino Directory as my LDAP server. Anyone who has worked with a Domino directory before knows that many Domino deployments have an O=Org suffix where Org is a company name containing spaces. For example, in our case it is "O=ARS GmbH". I would normally need to use this as the base DN (search base). However, ICP does not allow spaces in this field ... that need to be fixed! Any other LDAP client product I tried to connect to our Domino directory over many years was able to deal with spaces in the base DN.

Next, in a Domino directory usually the groups do have a different suffix (e.g. search base) than users. But ICP only offers ONE base DN field and not separate base DN fields for users and groups. Any other LDAP client ... DOES offer this. This needs to be fixed in ICP as well.

Next, the bind DN field does not allow some commonly used special characters which are often found in account names, such as the - character. This needs to be fixed as well (as it happens, the special user ID we have in our Domino directory which we use for LDAP binding is named dir-client ...).

Well, after hitting all those blocking problems, I finally tried to connect to our Microsoft Active Directory. This time I could successfully complete the LDAP connection. After doing so, I turned to "Users" and discovered I need to "Import group". However, no matter what I try to enter as (correct) values into the CN and OU fields, I only end up with an "internal server error".

Further more, after I could save the LDAP connection to Active Directory, I could no longer log in to the console with the builtin admin account! But since I could not import any users/groups, I could not assign that role to an LDAP account ... luckily, I had a VM snapshot of the master server and could thus revert to the state before.

This is really frustrating ...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into identical issue when hooking up to an openldap server running in a docker container.  It took me awhile to figure out the ICP pod and container where the log file is to get more information than "Internal Server Error".

Here is how to find the relevant ICP pod/container log:
Look for the "auth-idp" pods in the kube-system namespace.  I use:

```
kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system | grep auth-idp
```

If you are running an HA cluster, you will have a pod on each master node. 
In my case I have 3 master nodes.  If you are running only a single master, then you will have only one auth-idp pod.
Again, in an HA scenario, you need to figure out which is your current master node. (The easiest, crude way to do that is ssh to your master VIP and see which node you land on.)

Now figure out which pod is running on the current master node.  On each pod I use:

```
kubectl describe pod auth-idp-vq5bl --namespace=kube-system | grep IP
```

or

```
kubectl get pod auth-idp-vq5bl --namespace=kube-system -o wide
```

The one on the IP that is the current master node is where the log of interest will be.

The container in the pod that has the log of interest is: `platform-identity-mgmt`

To actually see the log file use:

```
kubectl logs auth-idp-vq5bl --namespace=kube-system --container=platform-identity-mgmt
```

At that point you will be able to scroll through the log and see a more detailed error message.

In the case of my error the log indicated my search filter for the group was not working properly.  I decided to mess with the user ID map and user filter so I used a user ID map of `*:cn` and a user filter of: `(&(cn=%v)(objectclass=inetOrgPerson))`  Once I changed those in the ICP LDAP configuration, the user import succeeded.  However, later I realized the logins were not working because the login is based on a search on `userid` or `uid`.  So I changed the user ID map back to `*:uid` and the user filter back to `(&(uid=%v)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson))`.  That corrected the login issue.  I added some users to my LDAP group and reimported the group and the import worked as well.  At this point, I'm not sure what was going on with the original import not working until I messed with the user ID map and user filter.  Go figure.

In my OpenLDAP directory instance my groups are all under ou=groups and each group member is listed as, e.g., cn=Peter Van Sickel,dc=ibm,dc=com. I had to edit the group member to get it using the full DN of an actual user.

My users are all directly under the root DN: dc=ibm,dc=com.

As to specific issues with other LDAPs, it is my experience that each has its own set of idiosyncrasies to get things working as desired.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I get the log (in my case, from auth-idp-vpvsv), I do not find any error message in it. Just a couple of "INFO:" messages. But no matter what I try, I cannot get any group loaded.

Comment: Also, my actual goal is to connect to a Domino directory. Active Directory would only be a 2nd class workaround.